# How to project hierarchy using Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models:

```
public class Addressbook() 
{
    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set;}
}

public class Person() 
{
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address() 
{
    public PostCode PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following method in my generic repository:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
{
    if (include.Any())
    {
        var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                    (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

        return set.Where(predicate);
    }

    return dbSet.Where(predicate);
}
```

To load an `Addressbook` I'm trying to do:

```
public override Addressbook Get(Expression<Func<Addressbook, bool>> predicate)
{
    return base.Get(predicate, x => x.Persons.Select(t => t.Title)
                                             .Select(a => a.Address)
                                             .Select(p => p.PostCode));
}
```

However, I get a compile error:

> Title does not contain a definition for Address.

What is the correct Linq syntax for this kind of projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `.Select(t => t.Title)`, which returns an `IEnumerable<Title>`. Then you're trying to `.Select(a => a.Address)` from it, but `Title` doesn't contain a member `Address` - `Person` does. So you're getting said compilation error.

Since you can supply multiple expressions to include by `params`, you should instead do this:

```
public override Addressbook Get(Expression<Func<Addressbook, bool>> predicate)
{
    return base.Get(predicate,
                    x => x.Persons.Select(person => person.Title),
                    x => x.Persons.Select(person => person.Address.PostCode));
}
```